# Get the contact details of a person from contact picker intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm trying to access the contact name,  phone number, and address of a person which I selected from contact picker intent.
Here is the code which I am using to open the contact picker Intent :

Here is the code which I am using :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

case PICK_CONTACT:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

          System.out.println("in on ActivityResult");
          Uri contactData = data.getData();
          Cursor c = getActivity().managedQuery(contactData, null, 
null, null, null);
          if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String id = 
c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));StringhasPhone=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
              Cursor phones             getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKind    s.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
              null,
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                  + " = " + id, null, null);
          phones.moveToFirst();
          String cNumber = 
phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));String name phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
          //here you can find out all the thing.
          System.out.println("NAME:"+name);
        }Cursor postal_cursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ 
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,


ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS},
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.MIMETYPE + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id), 
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
            null);
        postal_cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(postal_cursor.moveToNext())
        {
          String Strt = 
postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
          String Cty = 
 postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
          String cntry = 
 postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(

 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
          String address = 
postal_cursor.getString(postal_cursor.getColumnIndex(
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
        }
        postal_cursor.close();   }
```

but I am not able to get the address which is stored.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have [`READ_CONTACTS` permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), you'll only be able to get information from the `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` table, not specific info like phone or postal address.

If you'd like to get a phone, you can use the special phone-picker intent instead like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

or to get a postal address:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType(CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#PickContactDat

If you want to get both pieces of information, you'd need to ask the user for a [`READ_CONTACTS` permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) for those queries to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to get the name as well as the address from the contact picker. so how can I pass content type Phone and Structured Postal in intent?

Comment: you can choose either phone or postal in your intent, not both. to get the name you can use the same cursor of the phone or postal cursor, e.g. `Phone.CONTACT_NAME`

Comment: I'm trying  with phone in intent but not getting the postal address from curser

Comment: as i said, you can't have both using the same intent, unless you ask the user for READ_CONTACTS permission, and then you can query whatever you want from the ContactsContract APIs. If you don't have that permission you're only temporarily granted an option to get specific data about a contact (either phone or postal, but not both)